# PHP Hotel booking with allotments per day

Tags: php

Searched here for similar questions but I am finding stuff which is much more than I actually need.

What I am trying to do is to create a simple "hotel booking" with **allotments per day**.
So, basically: The user chooses a Checkin and a Checkout Date and Hotel A or Hotel B.

Now, for each day between Checkin and Checkout there are allotments, i.e. we have the following possible dates with respective allotments (rooms available):

```
Hotel A:
17.10.2014 - 25 rooms
18.10.2014 - 40 rooms
19.10.2014 - 20 rooms

Hotel B:
17.10.2014 - 35 rooms
18.10.2014 - 50 rooms
19.10.2014 - 40 rooms
```

When booking the user first chooses Checkin and Checkout, then the Hotel and THEN the script should check if any of the days in between is fully booked for that particular hotel and that particular date range and return a message that there are no free allotments for the selected date range - maybe also show which days are "problematic" (i.e. fully booked) so that the user can choose a day before or after.

What is the best approach to achieve this? I have checked several DB schemas for this and table structures, but as I said I am only finding other solutions, not exactly fit for this problem.

Comment: Have you written any code? We aren't here to write the code for you, we are here to help you with the code you have written.

Comment: Well, I tried a lot of code as given here in SO as example - right now I am left inbetween without any specific code. I wasn't asking for the complete Code - I was asking what the best APPROACH would be.

Comment: Best approach is just like any other problem create a database and store the records and then query the db for the count of records for any given date.